# Switch variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, switch-statement

While working on what can be called a "content slider" i wrote this piece of code up:

```js
var dayy = 1;

$(".buttonSix").click(function() {
  dayy--;
  console.log(dayy);
});

$(".buttonSeven").click(function() {
  dayy++;
  console.log(dayy);
});


switch (dayy)
{
  case 0:
    var dayy = 1;
    break;
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
    $(".fist").fadeOut();
    $(".second").fadeOut();
    $(".third").fadeIn();
    $(".fourth").fadeIn();
    break;
  case 3:
    $(".third").fadeOut();
    $(".fourth").fadeOut();
    $(".fith").fadeIn();
    $(".sicth").fadeIn();
    break;
  case 4:
    $(".fith").fadeOut();
    $(".sicth").fadeOut();
    $(".seventh").fadeIn();
    $(".eight").fadeIn();
    break;
  case 5:
    $(".seventh").fadeOut();
    $(".eight").fadeOut();
    $(".nineth").fadeIn();
    $(".tenth").fadeIn();
    break;
  case 6:
    $(".nineth").fadeOut();
    $(".tenth").fadeOut();
    $(".eleventh").fadeIn();
    $(".twelve").fadeIn();
    break;
  case 7:
    $(".eleventh").fadeOut();
    $(".twelve").fadeOut();
    $(".thirteenth").fadeIn();
    $(".fourteenth").fadeIn();
    break;
  default:
    $(".thirteenth").fadeOut();
    $(".fourteenth").fadeOut();
    $(".first").fadeIn();
    $(".second").fadeIn();
    var dayy = 1;
    break;
}
```

all the html divs have display none, except for first and second that are visible.
the increments are being logged and work but the switch isn't working.

no console errors are being logged

all help and comments are appreciated,
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch is not call after a click, it should be :

```
var dayy = 1;

    $(".buttonSix").click(function() {
      switchDayy(--dayy);
    });

    $(".buttonSeven").click(function() {
      switchDayy(++dayy)
    });

function switchDayy(dayy){
    switch (dayy) {
      case 0:
        var dayy = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        break;
      case 2:
        $(".fist").fadeOut();
        $(".second").fadeOut();
        $(".third").fadeIn();
        $(".fourth").fadeIn();
        break;
      case 3:
        $(".third").fadeOut();
        $(".fourth").fadeOut();
        $(".fith").fadeIn();
        $(".sicth").fadeIn();
        break;
      case 4:
        $(".fith").fadeOut();
        $(".sicth").fadeOut();
        $(".seventh").fadeIn();
        $(".eight").fadeIn();
        break;
      case 5:
        $(".seventh").fadeOut();
        $(".eight").fadeOut();
        $(".nineth").fadeIn();
        $(".tenth").fadeIn();
        break;
      case 6:
        $(".nineth").fadeOut();
        $(".tenth").fadeOut();
        $(".eleventh").fadeIn();
        $(".twelve").fadeIn();
        break;
      case 7:
        $(".eleventh").fadeOut();
        $(".twelve").fadeOut();
        $(".thirteenth").fadeIn();
        $(".fourteenth").fadeIn();
        break;
      default:
        $(".thirteenth").fadeOut();
        $(".fourteenth").fadeOut();
        $(".first").fadeIn();
        $(".second").fadeIn();
        var dayy = 1;
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look right at all, there are way too many `var dayy = 1;` in this piece of code.

Comment: @Musa got rid of the var and left just the dayy = 1 as the var was not needed, but the rest of the code does get the job done:) Thanks!

Comment: @Musa Yeah sure it's more like pseudo code than real code since the click has to be in a document ready function in a separate part of the code. Only one global var dayy should be enough and then it will be useless to have it has a parameter on switchDayy(),